# Insert Python variable into Oracle Database

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I can successfully insert an entire DataFrame into my Oracle table, but I cannot figure out how to insert a single variable into my it. I've failed using both bind variables and regular Python variables.

My variable `year` prints out `2014`, in this case, because my code parses the year out of the document I run it on; and it'll eventually have to be run on 100's of documents.

So my SQL statements are as follows:

```
cursor = con.cursor()
exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df_Quota.values]
new_variable = year
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, money, sector_name, ask)" "VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, 'NEFS 2', '1')")
year_command = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(trade_year)" "VALUES (:1)")
cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
cursor.executemany(year_command, new_variable)
con.commit() 

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

and that fails with the error `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`... It also fails when I simply try:

```
year_command = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(trade_year)" "VALUES (year)")
cursor.execute(year_command)
```

with the error `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here`...

So I am very confused as to how to get a single Python variable into my Oracle table. Ideally I would like for the value of my variable `year` to export to the column `trade_year` in my Oracle table. Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
df_Quota:

   AvailableQuota DatePosted    ID LiveWeightPounds   price
0         GOM COD       5/20  1724             2328  $9,000
1        GOM HADD       5/20  1724              445  $9,000
2          GOM BB       5/20  1724             3007  $9,000
3        GREYSOLE       5/20  1724              850  $9,000
4            DABS       5/20  1724             3101  $9,000
5          GOM YT       5/20  1724             1995  $9,000
6         GBE COD       5/20  1578              538   $1.00
7           GB BB       5/20  1578             1755   $0.20
8           GB YT       5/20  1578              243   $1.00
9          SNE BB       5/20  1578              490   $0.45
10         SNE YT       5/20  1578              153   $0.50
11         GOM BB       5/20  1578             3965   $0.15
12          Whake       5/20  1578             2727   $0.20
13           POLL       5/20  1578             9227   $0.01
14            RED       5/20  1578            15060   $0.01
15        GBE COD       5/20   310              825  15,000
16        GBW COD       5/20   310             9033  15,000
17           DABS       5/20   310            12419  15,000
18          WHAKE       5/20   310             3120  15,000
19           POLL       5/20   310            65234  15,000
20            RED       5/20   310            76610  15,000
21         SNE BB       5/20   310             2121  15,000
22         GOM BB       5/20   310             7285  15,000
```

Comment: Curious, why don't you use pandas' [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) for the dataframe insert?

Comment: I didn't actually know Pandas had that function...I'm kind of a noob with Pandas and only recently discovered it can also read_html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv,sys

dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "1521", "xxxxxxxx")
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="scott", password="tiger", dsn=dsnStr)
print "Database version " + con.version

myCur = con.cursor()
myCur.prepare( 'insert into roughtable( trade_year ) values ( :theYear )' )

myYear='2016'
myCur.execute(None, {'theYear':myYear})
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: But instead of setting `myYear` equal to '2016' I would like to set it to a variable because in each document I run my code on, it'll parse out whatever year is in the document, so that value will change.

Comment: @theprowler Yes, I understand that. myYear *is* a variable. So you can set it to anything you want in your program. What I was showing you was how to bind a program variable to the sql statement.

Comment: Now, if you want to write a bunch of myYears to the database, you can populate an array (list I think in python lingo) and bind the array, and performs an "array inset" ( in Oracle lingo)

Comment: Ohhhhh ok ok ok that makes a lot of sense. Give me a sec and I'll try it all right now, thanks

Comment: @theprowler I'll add an array insert example in about an hour (I need to check in for a flight :) )

Comment: Crap....I just realized I didn't ask my question right at all... So your code worked perfectly and I'll up-vote it and check it off as correct, but it's not precisely what I wanted to accomplish since I asked the question a little incorrectly... So I have that entire DataFrame of data (`df_Quota`), which I edited into my question above, and what I actually want to happen is for that year (`myYear`) to appear at the end of every row in `df_Quota`... Is that a difficult maneuver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134203/discussion-between-bobc-and-theprowler).